# Stored procedures

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that inserts a user into a table but I want an output value equals to the new inserted `UserID` in the table but I don't know how to do it can you guys help me?

I have this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.st_Insert_User
(
@Nombre varchar(200),
@Usuario varchar(100),
@Password varchar(100),
@Administrador bit,
@Resultado int output
)
AS
INSERT INTO tbl_Users(Nombre, Usuario, Password, Administrador)
VALUES(@Nombre, @Usuario, @Password, @Administrador)

    SELECT @resultado = UserID
```

I also tried

```
SELECT @resultado = UserID FROM tbl_Users WHERE Usuario = @Usuario
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add at the end

select @@Identity

Comment: `@@identity` should not be used here. `scope_identity()` is the correct thing to use as it won't suddenly break if a trigger gets added to the table that inserts to another table with an `identity` column.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

will give you the identity of the row

Answer (score 3):

For SQL Server, you want to use the OUTPUT clause. See information and examples in [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) here. It does cover your case-- as it mentions "The OUTPUT clause may be useful to retrieve the value of identity or computed columns after an INSERT or UPDATE operation."

(If this is for real world purposes, you do of course have security concerns in storing passwords that you should address.)